# Adding type annotations to classes in racket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

Trying to finish up an implementation of Conway's Game of Life in Racket and I'm adding types to everything. I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly I need to do to get the classes from the gui lib typed correctly.

```
(: new-timer (Instance Timer%))
(define new-timer (new timer% [interval 400]
                       [notify-callback (lambda () (begin
                                                     (set-field! grd cv (next-grid (get-field grd cv) ROW COLUMNS))
                                                     (send cv on-paint)))]))
(: new-canvas% Canvas%)
(define new-canvas% (class canvas%
              (super-new)
              (inherit get-dc suspend-flush resume-flush)
              (field [dc : (Instance DC<%>) (get-dc)] [grd : Grid (make-grid ROW COLUMNS)])
              (define/override (on-char char)
            (let ([event (send char get-key-code)])
              (cond

                            [(and (char? event) (char=? event #\space)) (send new-timer stop)])))


                      (define/override (on-paint)
                        (send dc erase)
                        (suspend-flush)
                        (render-grid grd ROW COLUMNS dc)
                        (resume-flush))))

(: cv (Instance Canvas%))
(define cv (new new-canvas% [parent main-frame]))
```

I'm getting this error below

```
/Documents/conways-game-of-life/main.rkt:49:83: Type Checker: type mismatch;
;  the object is missing an expected field
;   field: grd
;   object type: (Instance Canvas%)
;   in: (get-field grd cv)
; Context:
;  /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/promise.rkt:128:5
; /home/diego/Documents/conways-game-of-life/main.rkt:49:53: Type Checker: type mismatch;
;  expected an object with field grd
;   given: (Instance Canvas%)
;   in: (set-field! grd cv (next-grid (get-field grd cv) ROW COLUMNS))
```

I think it because canvas doesn't normally have a grd field but every time I try to give my canvas the type declaration `(: cv (Instance new-canvas%))` It says it's unbound. Full file and all code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/diegocrespo/conways-game-of-life/-/blob/master/main.rkt). Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of `new-timer`, you're trying to get the `grd` field of `cv`.

And although `cv` is an instance of the class `new-canvas%`, its type does not include that field. You need to create a new `Class` type for `new-canvas%`. By convention, it should be a capitalized version like `New-Canvas%`.

```
(define-type New-Canvas% (Class ....))

(: new-canvas% New-Canvas%)
(define new-canvas% (class ....))

(: cv (Instance New-Canvas%))
(define cv (new .....))
```

The `New-Canvas%` type you define using `Class` should specify the new field `grd`, as well as specifying that it's a subclass of `Canvas%`.

Comment: I'm still having some trouble The updated code is here https://pastebin.com/kiXXXrZg The error is about the class "class has init `stretchable-height' that is not in expected type" which I think has something to do with the #:implements not working as I expected. Thanks for the initial help!

Comment: Try `#:implements/inits` instead